# Discover program's image in memory

Tags: c, memory

Here's something less-than-important that I've been musing about recently:

I know that my program's virtual address space contains the stack (of each thread) and a heap and some statically allocated memory and all that. But does it also contain the program's image with all the instructions? And is it possible somehow (no matter how platform dependent the trick) to find out the address range of my own image? Is the memory read-only?

In short: Can I make a program that prints itself?

If that can't be done, a lesser question would be, can I print my own stack? I was thinking something like this:

```
const char * BASE;

void print_stack();

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  BASE = &argc;
  /* do stuff */
  print_stack();
  return 0;
}

void print_stack() {
  int sentinel;
  const char * bottom = &sentinel;
  while (bottom < BASE)
    printf("%02X ", *bottom++);
}
```

Comment: @Joe: Thanks, I never knew of `<execinfo.h>`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, of course it contains your program's instructions: you can only execute what you can access. To get at the address of your instructions, you can take the address of a function and start printing from there. You can then use a library like [udis86](http://udis86.sourceforge.net/) to disassemble them. Note however, that your compiler isn't required to order the functions in any specific way, so starting at `main` and reading from there isn't guaranteed to get everything, might trample on un-allocated memory.

To get at the entire instruction memory range (you're looking for the `.text` segment), you can look up the address+size from your operating system (In Linux, that info will be in `/proc/[pid]/maps`, in OS X you can either use `vmmap` or ask the kernel via the `mach_vm_region()` kernel trap), and then just read the memory directly. You can also use `nm` to dump the symbols of your program, isolate all that point to the `.text` segment (They should be marked with `T` in `nm` output) and dump those. This is not a good method, since you'd have to disassemble everything to determine where they end in the case there's padding between them.

All the mapped memory is accessible, but not all of it will be writeable (The `.text` segment wouldn't be). One thing to keep in mind, the addresses will probably not be stable invocation to invocation if your operating system implements ASLR.

To address your second question, yes you can print your own stack and symbolicate it with the help of third-party libraries, but not the way you're trying to do it. Stack typically grows *down* (i.e. Starts at a high address and moves towards lower addresses. As an exercise to the reader, disassemble one of your functions via `gdb` or another disassembler and look how memory on the stack gets allocated during your function prolog), so your for-loop will never run as `BASE` will probably always be larger than the address of `sentinel`.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips! I'll look at `/proc/[pid]/maps`, very interesting. I didn't want to `nm`, I just wanted to poke around the live memory during execution. Of course the stack goes down, d'oh. I'll fix that!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the code bytes, usually called the program "text" in this context, is part of your virtual address space.

You can determine the address of a function, e.g. `main()`, and use that to determine a single valid address in a range of text pages.  You will then have to call virtual memory specific APIs to determine the extent of the mapping at that address.

Shared libraries (.so files) will have their texts mapped to discontiguous VM regions.

Comment: Are all my functions vaguely contiguous, i.e. if I start printing from `&main` until I segfault, would I see everything?

Comment: Usually, all the .o files you link together are placed in a contiguous range.  This isn't guaranteed by any standard.  Within a .o file, the code bytes are almost always contiguous.  main won't necessarily be at the beginning of this range of memory, either.  If you start reading from an address and move either direction from there, you might move into heap, stack, or data memory without noticing.

Comment: Fun. Can I ask the OS if a given address has been allocated to me? That way I could walk in both directions and stop when I go out of bounds.

Comment: In Windows you can use VirtualQueryEx().  In Linux, you have to parse the files in /proc filesystem.  Each Unix has its own method for determining the ranges.